# Detect Javascript being disabled *after* page load

Tags: html, pageload, javascript

I have come across several posts about how to handle Javascript being disabled **while/before** the page is being loaded. However, is there any way to detect Javascript being disabled by the user **after** the page has loaded in order to hide content at the last minute?

Comment: Are you saying you want to handle a sort of "user just turned off JS" event that occurs while the current page is open but before any further navigation/submit/reload of the page?

Comment: Exactly, an event to fire right before JS gets disabled to allow one last function to run to hide content should they choose to disable JS.

Comment: How *do* you turn off JS after the page has loaded? That's why I've been trying to figure out. When you disable javascript in Chrome, you have to refresh the page for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

- Use a dead man switch on setInterval. If it doesn't trip the trigger, then you need to hide that content before the no javascript gremlins destroys it. How can you hide it without javascript? Have a competitive process going between CSS animations, and Javascript. Such that if javascript is not present the CSS animations (to hide the content), win out. And lo, the content waseth hiddeneth.
- Attempt to an send an HTTP request to your server? If that ping doesn't arrive, javascript could be disabled.
- Use a noscript tag to inform the user of various things in the event that javascript is disabled, such as the fact that the user has javascript disabled
- Put a form in a noscript tag to ask a user to tell you that javascript is disabled, or otherwise to send feedback about their browsing experience to your site without javascript
- Check if the UserAgent header contains Lynx?

Comment: Doesn't the setInterval require JS to function as a deadman switch? The ping option actually might work quite well.

Comment: Isn't it difficult to figure out if ping doesn't arrive ? How can you find out that

Comment: @user3394898 yes, so it is an indicator of javascript live-ness, no? If no setInterval, then CSS wins and the content vanishes. `setInterval( preventContentFromDisappearing, 1000 )`

Comment: @Cris Gotcha, I like this idea and think this just might solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Cris It seems CSS animations aren't supported within the assessment tool we use. I'll have to consider the ping idea for the time being. Thanks for the insight on this one though!

Comment: @Cris - It seems the assessment tool does support CSS animations and I was able to wrap the text in a <div> and use keyframes to drop the opacity down to 0.0. However, it seems that my JavaScript cannot get the div element by id and re-raise the opacity to negate the CSS. Would you happen to know if JS cannot interfere with CSS animations mid-animation-sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if a particular user had disabled JS on his browser by using **cookies**. You can assume that your JS sets a cookie with some key-value pair like `js-enabled=true`

When the page gets loaded next time, if cookie does not contain js-enabled key then you know that JS is disabled on the page and server returns the content accordingly.

Now, your question:

> After the page has loaded in order to hide content at the last minute?

Say even if you know JS is disabled on the browser, how will you hide the content. You again need JS to be executed to manipulate the DOM which is not possible I think when JS is disabled. So one of the solutions can be when your server knows that JS is disabled then return the page which does not have that content which you want to hide

Comment: How does that help with the "hide content at the last minute" part of the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the page is for an online assessment tool and only gets loaded once. We are trying to prevent the user from loading the assessment questions, disabling Javascript, and then taking screenshots. I was hoping it might be possible to get one last-minute Javascript function to run before it is disabled in order to hide the assessment questions via CSS.

Comment: @user3394898 - If you did hide the assessment questions via CSS the user could just use the browsers dev tools to unhide them again. I don't think there's any way you can stop the user taking screenshots. I mean, even if they're not technically savvy they can use a camera to take a photograph of the screen...

Comment: @user3394898 How can you stop user from hitting <kbd>printscreen</kbd> button on keyboard.

Comment: Basically the way it works now is, the printscreen key is pressed, we capture that and send a notice to our servers via JS. However, if JS is disabled, that functionality goes away. It's not that we are trying to prevent the printscreen from being pressed but just alerting us when it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to show a warning when javascript is disabled before loading: Write a div element with a warning that jscript is disabled and hide it with jscript while loading the webpage. It is not possible to show a warning when javascript is disabled, because javascript is needed to change any part of a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

if your app can stand the hit of doing log checks - I would, say every minute or so, use ajax to call
the backend - which will then log a time. if the backend checks and the last log time is substantially off - then shut down the app.